# Java, setForeground in paintComponent melts CPU

Tags: java, swing, cpu, jlabel, shadow

I had problems to find / create a JLabel with shadow which supports all the old JLabel features (Html tags). So I tried this and it looks good and the JLabel works like before.

```
public class SLabel extends JLabel {
    public SLabel() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // Use Foregroundcolor for the text
        // Use Backgroundcolor for the shadow
        Color c = getForeground();
        setForeground(getBackground());
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create(-2, -2, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
        setForeground(c); //<-Remove this line and CPU acts normal
        super.paintComponent(g2.create());
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

But I recently got a new computer with windows 10 and I observed a very high cpu usage while displaying this JLabel (followed by loud fan noises).

It seems that `setForeground(c)` is the codeline which increases the CPU usage.

Any idea why, any alternative codesamples for a Shadowed JLabel with HTML tags or improvements of my code?

Comment: The reason is simple: `setForeground` causes a `repaint` internally, sending the system into an endless chain of paint events. Alleviating this is not trivial, depending on the exact requirements of the resulting component...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, that's what it does. Painting should do nothing more then simply paint the current state, it should never try to alter the state of the component, because this can generate new paint requests

What you actually need to do, is generate a "snapshot" of the label first, which becomes part of the "effect" you want to generate, you then paint this to the supplied `Graphics` context when `paintComponent` is called, for example...

[image: DropShadow]

## DropShadowLabel

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class DropShadowLabel extends AbstractEffectLabel {

    private int shadowSize;
    private Color shadowColor;
    private float shadowAlpha;

    public DropShadowLabel() {

        setShadowSize(2);
        setShadowColor(Color.BLACK);
        setShadowAlpha(0.5f);

    }

    @Override
    protected BufferedImage applyEffectTo(BufferedImage img) {
        return ImageEffectUtilities.applyDropShadow(img, getShadowSize(), getShadowColor(), getShadowAlpha());
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getEffectInsets() {

        return new Insets(0, 0, (getShadowSize() * 2), (getShadowSize() * 2));

    }

    public void setShadowAlpha(float value) {

        if (shadowAlpha != value) {

            float old = shadowAlpha;
            shadowAlpha = value;

            firePropertyChange("shadowAlpha", old, value);
            invalidate();
            repaint();

        }

    }

    public void setShadowColor(Color value) {

        if (shadowColor != value) {

            Color old = shadowColor;
            shadowColor = value;

            firePropertyChange("shadowColor", old, value);
            invalidate();
            repaint();

        }

    }

    public void setShadowSize(int value) {

        if (shadowSize != value) {

            int old = shadowSize;
            shadowSize = value;

            updateRendererSize();

            firePropertyChange("shadowSize", old, value);
            invalidate();
            repaint();

        }

    }

    public float getShadowAlpha() {
        return shadowAlpha;
    }

    public Color getShadowColor() {
        return shadowColor;
    }

    public int getShadowSize() {
        return shadowSize;
    }

}
```

## AbstractEffectLabel

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public abstract class AbstractEffectLabel extends JComponent {

    private JLabel renderer;

    private BufferedImage imgCache;

    public AbstractEffectLabel() {
    }

    protected JLabel getRenderer() {

        if (renderer == null) {

            renderer = new JLabel();
            renderer.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.LEFT);
            renderer.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);

        }

        return renderer;

    }

    @Override
    public void setForeground(Color fg) {
        super.setForeground(fg);
        getRenderer().setForeground(fg);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackground(Color bg) {
        super.setBackground(bg);
        getRenderer().setBackground(bg);
    }

    @Override
    public Font getFont() {
        return getRenderer().getFont();
    }

    public void setHorizontalAlignment(int alignment) {

        getRenderer().setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);

    }

    public void setVerticalAlignment(int alignment) {

        getRenderer().setVerticalAlignment(alignment);

    }

    public void setHorizontalTextPosition(int alignment) {

        getRenderer().setHorizontalTextPosition(alignment);

    }

    public void setVerticalTextPosition(int alignment) {

        getRenderer().setVerticalTextPosition(alignment);

    }

    public int getHorizontalAlignment() {

        return getRenderer().getHorizontalAlignment();

    }

    public int getVerticalAlignment() {

        return getRenderer().getVerticalAlignment();

    }

    public int getHorizontalTextPosition() {

        return getRenderer().getHorizontalTextPosition();

    }

    public int getVerticalTextPosition() {

        return getRenderer().getVerticalTextPosition();

    }

    @Override
    public void setFont(Font font) {

        super.setFont(font);

        getRenderer().setFont(font);

        updateRendererSize();

    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {

        imgCache = null;

        super.invalidate();

    }

    public void setText(String text) {

        getRenderer().setText(text);

        updateRendererSize();

        invalidate();
        repaint();

    }

    public String getText() {

        return getRenderer().getText();

    }

    protected abstract BufferedImage applyEffectTo(BufferedImage img);

    protected BufferedImage getImageCache() {

        if (imgCache == null) {

            JLabel renderer = getRenderer();

            imgCache = ImageEffectUtilities.createCompatibleImage(Math.max(1, renderer.getWidth()), Math.max(renderer.getHeight(), 1));
            Graphics2D g2d = imgCache.createGraphics();

            renderer.setForeground(getForeground());

            renderer.paint(g2d);

            g2d.dispose();

//          imgCache = GlowEffectFactory.applyDropShadow(imgCache, getShadowSize(), getShadowColor(), getShadowAlpha());
            imgCache = applyEffectTo(imgCache);

        }

        return imgCache;

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        Rectangle bounds = UIUtilities.getSafeBounds(this);
        g2d.drawImage(getImageCache(), bounds.x, bounds.y, this);

    }

    public abstract Insets getEffectInsets();

    protected void updateRendererSize() {

        Dimension prefSize = getRenderer().getPreferredSize();

        Insets insets = getEffectInsets();

        prefSize.width += (insets.left + insets.right);
        prefSize.height += (insets.top + insets.bottom);

        getRenderer().setSize(prefSize);

        setPreferredSize(prefSize);
        setMinimumSize(prefSize);

    }

}
```

## ImageEffectUtilities

```
import com.jhlabs.image.GaussianFilter;
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class ImageEffectUtilities {

    public static BufferedImage applyDropShadow(BufferedImage imgMaster, int size, Color color, float opactity) {
        return applyEffect(imgMaster, 0, 0, size, color, opactity);
    }

    protected static BufferedImage applyEffect(BufferedImage imgMaster, int xOffset, int yOffset, int size, Color color, float opactity) {

        BufferedImage imgShadow = generateShadow(imgMaster, size, color, opactity);

        BufferedImage imgCombined = createCompatibleImage(imgShadow);
        Graphics2D g2d = imgCombined.createGraphics();
        GraphicsUtilities.applyQualityRenderingHints(g2d);

        g2d.drawImage(imgShadow, -(size / 2), -(size / 2), null);
        g2d.drawImage(imgMaster, xOffset, yOffset, null);

        g2d.dispose();

        return imgCombined;

    }

    public static BufferedImage generateShadow(BufferedImage imgSource, int size, Color color, float alpha) {

        int imgWidth = imgSource.getWidth() + (size * 2);
        int imgHeight = imgSource.getHeight() + (size * 2);

        BufferedImage imgMask = createCompatibleImage(imgWidth, imgHeight);
        Graphics2D g2 = imgMask.createGraphics();

        int    x = Math.round((imgWidth - imgSource.getWidth()) / 2f);
        int    y = Math.round((imgHeight - imgSource.getHeight()) / 2f);
        g2.drawImage(imgSource, x, y, null);
        g2.dispose();

        // ---- Blur here ---

        BufferedImage imgGlow = generateBlur(imgMask, (size * 2), color, alpha);

        // ---- Blur here ----

        return imgGlow;

    }


    public static BufferedImage generateBlur(BufferedImage imgSource, int size, Color color, float alpha) {

        GaussianFilter filter = new GaussianFilter(size);

        int imgWidth = imgSource.getWidth();
        int imgHeight = imgSource.getHeight();

        BufferedImage imgBlur = createCompatibleImage(imgWidth, imgHeight);
        Graphics2D g2 = imgBlur.createGraphics();

        g2.drawImage(imgSource, 0, 0, null);
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_IN, alpha));
        g2.setColor(color);

        g2.fillRect(0, 0, imgSource.getWidth(), imgSource.getHeight());
        g2.dispose();

        imgBlur = filter.filter(imgBlur, null);

        return imgBlur;

    }


    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(int width, int height) {
        return createCompatibleImage(width, height, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
    }

    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(int width, int height, int transparency) {
        BufferedImage image = getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height, transparency);
        image.coerceData(true);
        return image;
    }

    public static GraphicsConfiguration getGraphicsConfiguration() {
        return GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    }

    public static Rectangle getSafeBounds(JComponent comp) {

        Insets insets = comp.getInsets();

        return getSafeBounds(insets, comp.getBounds());
    }


    public static Rectangle getSafeBounds(Insets insets, Rectangle bounds) {

        int x = insets.left;
        int y = insets.top;
        int width = bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right);
        int height = bounds.height - (insets.top + insets.bottom);

        return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

    }

}
```

You'll also need the [JHLabs Filters](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html)

**Extended Example**

`JLabel` is a complex component, with icon support, text and icon positioning.  The main reason I wrote the above code the way it is, is because I really don't want to have to reimplement a lot of that work, and also because the label can render html and the way in which the label is rendered is different from the way `Graphics#drawString` does it (don't know why, it just is).

Below is an extended example, in which I added `icon` support to the `AbstractEffectLabel` and for comparison, the bottom one is just a plain old `JLabel`

[image: Extended example]

Comment: @Marco13 No, I wrote this a some time ago.  Sorry, had to rummage through my library code to reduce the functionality to what you needed into the `ImageEffectUtilities` class (I hope :P)

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Its alot of code for a simple problem so would it be ok to just block the repaint method while painting the component? (This worked for me too)

Comment: @Kain yes, that's what you needed to do. As explained by pvg and Marco 13 :)

Comment: @Kain The problem is, the only time you know for sure your component is to be repainted is when paint is actually called, not all repaints are triggered directly by the component itself

Comment: @Marco13 The reason there is "a lot of code" is this has been built and refined up over time, I use (a lot) of the code to generate shadow and glow effects, so the code compartmentalised to achieve a specific job, which can then utilised by other apis and algorithms

Comment: I see, over time one builds an own "repository" of code snippets that are used frequently in answers (some parts seem to be missing, `ImageUtilities` - but likely, one could find them in other answers ;-)). Still I think that for a simple drop shadow, there must be an easier way. Imagine it with custom painting: It would just be `drawString(x+2,y+2,s)` and `drawString(x,y,s)`. I thought that is might be possible to manually "hook" into the `BasicLabelUI` and let it do the desired painting 2 times...(maybe I'll try this later) (btw: I started deleting obsolete comments from the top)

Comment: Well, not for answers, just for re-usable code :P - I tried to take all the library code and wrap it up in the `ImageEffectUtilities`, but might have forgotten to change the class references.  I did try to use `drawString`, but one, it doesn't render HTML and two, it doesn't render the same way `JLabel` does, which is why I have a `JLabel` which I use to render to an offscreen `BufferedImage`, which is then "blured' to produce the drop shadow.  If you don't need the blur effect, much of the "library" code isn't required. Using a `BasicLabelUI`, is generally the same thing ;P

Comment: `JLabel` is also a complex component, with icon support and text and icon positioning.  The "library" code I've provided is also used to generate drop shadows for non-rectangular components and images as well as other effects, like glow and blur effects, hence the reason it's compartmentalised. Check out the update, where I've added `icon` support for the `AbstractEffectLabel` class ;)

Answer (score 2):

When `setForeground` is called with a different color, a repaint is triggered, so you're constantly triggering repaints. See http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/swing/JComponent.java#JComponent.setForeground%28java.awt.Color%29